# PowerPoint VBA Macro for deleting charts

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I have implemented a VBA macro for deleting charts in a Power Point document.
The code is as follows:

```
Sub cleanCharts()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sld As Slide

'Loop Through Each Slide in ActivePresentation
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasChart Then
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next shp
  Next sld
End Sub
```

The thing is: the Macro do what is supposed to do, but not at first try. I need to run it several times, and after three or four, all charts were deleted. First time I execute it, only half of all charts were deleted, etc...
What is missing?

Regards

Comment: Perhaps deleting action changes array structure for Shapes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. Following code do it in one try:

```
Sub limpiaGraficas()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim i, num

'Loop Through Each Slide in ActivePresentation
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    num = sld.Shapes.Count
    For i = num To 1 Step -1
        If sld.Shapes(i).HasChart Then
            sld.Shapes(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
  Next sld
End Sub
```

Basically: running the loop in reverse order for the Shapes makes the difference. I suppose its because deleting elements in Shapes alters the structure of the array.

Comment: Then this works the same way as deleting rows in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `HasChart` is the best option for what you are trying to achieve.

What about if you try with `Type` property?

```
If shp.Type = msoChart Then
    shp.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Applied changes, but same result. Half charts deleted in each execution.

Comment: What about if you try to debug your code and print the properties of every shape in your immediate window? This can give you a hint if your machine is so fast or something else is happening.

Comment: ok. What command should I code to see the properties of every shape?

Comment: There are several ways to do that. `Debug.Print shp.Type` another is run step by step using `F8` and when you are in the loop of every shape use your `Locals` window to see all the properties.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I got it. I'll write the answer below.